# Twitter Bootstrap Popover: repositioning or resizing after dynamically generating data?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have few popover buttons which on clicked get the popover information dynamically. I was able to get the correct info for its respective buttons but was having a difficult time to re-position or re-size the popover window.

[Here's the link] http://bootply.com/87953  where the problem could be seen.

I have modified my code for the sake of simplifying the problem I'm facing.

Any suggestion on how to re-size or re-position the popover using only JavaScript is appreciated?

Comment: Are you loading the content dynamically using ajax or something?

Comment: @PSL: Yes I am using ajax

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for updating popover properties using javascript. In my example I have updated the content, title and placement of popover on the click of a button. You can refer this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/Veqnh/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="span1 offset1" style="margin:100px">
     <a href="#" id="qoo" rel="popover" class="circle"> Click to popover</a>
     <div id="content-wrapper1" class="content-wrapper"> texttttttat</div> 
</div>

<input type="button" id="change_content" value="Change Popover content and placement">
```

JS :

```
$('#qoo').popover({
    placement : 'right',
    html : true,
    delay: { 
             show: 500, 
             hide: 500
    },
    title:'old_title',
    content: function() {
        return $('#content-wrapper1').html();
    }                 

});

$('#change_content').click(function(){
    alert('Popover title, content and placement changed');
    $('#qoo').popover('destroy');

    $('#qoo').popover({
        content:'new content',
        title:'new title',
        placement:'top'
    });
});
```